# Cyclic dependencies in spring Beans: what's wrong with it?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean, cyclic-dependency

I've heard many times a "cyclic beans problem" in spring framework.
Could anyone describe when does it appear? I see 3 cases:

1. Bean A has autowired field of bean B, bean B has autowired field A. No constructors, no setters.
2. Both A and B has fields of each other. Bean A has a constructor with bean B there, bean B has has a constructor with bean A there (both constructors initialize the fields)
3. Both A and B has fields of each other. Bean A has a setter with bean B there, bean B has has a setter with bean A there (both setters initialize the fields)

Please, designate, which case has a problem? How to solve?